# ProviderNotFoundException: No AuthenticationProvider found for ExpiringUsernameAuthenticationToken

Tags: spring-security, spring-saml

We have developed an application using Spring Security and Spring SAML that works in our development environment where we use SSOCircle as our IDP. When we move into our customer's environment using their IDP, we are able to authenticate and navigate through the application without a problem as long as we do not pause. If the user pauses on a page for more than minute before submitting it, the application will redirect to the original landing page and the submitted data is lost.

The logs show:

```
o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter
                - Authentication exception occurred; redirecting to authentication entry point
org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderNotFoundException: No AuthenticationProvider found for org.springframework.security.providers.ExpiringUsernameAuthenticationToken
```

Prior to this you the logs show at about every minute something similar to:

```
SecurityContextHolder not populated with anonymous token, as it already contained: 'org.springframework.security.providers.ExpiringUsernameAuthenticationToken@e6313ceb: Principal: REDACTED
```

We have been told by the customer that their IDP has a timeout of 60 seconds with a +-30sec skew time.

We asked them to temporarily adjust the IDP timeout to 30 minutes and our problem went away. When we go to production we must have the original setting of 60 seconds.

Our application is using the SAMLAuthenticationProvider:

```
@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
        throws Exception {
    auth.authenticationProvider(samlAuthenticationProvider());
}

@Bean
public SAMLAuthenticationProvider samlAuthenticationProvider() {
    SAMLAuthenticationProvider samlAuthenticationProvider = new SAMLAuthenticationProvider();
    samlAuthenticationProvider.setForcePrincipalAsString(false);
    samlAuthenticationProvider.setUserDetails(samlUserDetailsService);
    return samlAuthenticationProvider;
}
```

How do we configure ExpiringUsernameAuthenticationToken to use this? And why does the original authentication work if it is not set?

And why is the application trying to re-authenticate when the IDP's session expires?

WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl and SingleLogoutProfileImpl both provide ways to set the responseSkew. Should this be set equal to, less than, or greater than the IDP's skew time?

Comment: So your customer's IDP is setting SessionNotOnOrAfter in the SAML Response and only including 60 seconds in the future in it? What is the behavior you want to observe? Ignore the 60 second timeout?

Comment: Yes, approximately. At 15:39:45, they sent NotOnOrAfter="2015-02-23T15:41:14Z".

Comment: After someone authenticates, we would like them to have normal behavior until the app's HttpSession expires or they logout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring SAML by default observes the `SessionNotOnOrAfter` field provided by IDP in its SAML Response. This field tells that that once time hits the provided value user must be re-authenticated.

Spring SAML tries to re-authenticate user by sending the current `Authentication` object to `AuthenticationManager`, which tries to find an `AuhenticationProvier` which supports `Authentiction` object of such type (`ExpiringUsernameAuthenticationToken` in case of Spring SAML). In your case there is no such provider - that's why you see the `ProviderNotFoundException` exception. After this error Spring Security probably invokes the default `EntryPoint`, which redirects your user to the login page.

In order to ignore the `SessionNotOnOrAfter` value simply extend class `SAMLAuthenticationProvider`, override method `getExpirationDate` and make it return `null`. Then use your new class in the `securityContext.xml`.

But the correct solution is for your IDP to return `SessionNotOnOrAfter` value with a sensible session length - I wonder why they insist on using 60 seconds there.

Comment: Thank you, @Vladimír Schäfer. I'll be testing this shortly. Do you know of any 'official' recommendations for setting SessionNotOnOrAfter that I could use to help convince them?

Comment: I'd argue with them that the value should be similar to usual maximum time of an HTTP session - as they have essentially same meaning. But  it's probably much easier to simply ignore the value - just let them know that this is the way the SP will be implemented and get a consent. Some other vendors also ignore the value altogether (e.g. Ping - https://ping.force.com/Support/PingIdentityArticle?id=kA3400000008RdNCAU)